# Getting OpenVPN server status failed after fully configuration on Centos 7 VPS

Tags: docker, openvpn, centos7, vps

I am going to setup a `VPN Server` on `Centos 7` VPS, running as Docker container. However, after installing `OpenVPN` and configuring it, I see the server status failed:
[image]

This is my **server.conf** file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

And this is what written in `messages` file in var/log/ after run command below:

> systemctl start openvpn@server.service

```
Oct  7 08:35:39 systemd: Cannot add dependency job for unit systemd-vconsole-setup.service, ignoring: Unit is masked.
Oct  7 08:35:39 systemd: Starting OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server...
Oct  7 08:35:39 openvpn: Fri Oct  7 08:35:39 2022 OpenVPN 2.4.12 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [Fedora EPEL patched] [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 17 2022
Oct  7 08:35:39 openvpn: Fri Oct  7 08:35:39 2022 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.06
Oct  7 08:35:39 openvpn: Fri Oct  7 08:35:39 2022 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Oct  7 08:35:39 openvpn: Fri Oct  7 08:35:39 2022 ROUTE_GATEWAY ON_LINK IFACE=venet0 HWADDR=00:00:00:00:00:00
Oct  7 08:35:39 openvpn: Fri Oct  7 08:35:39 2022 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)
Oct  7 08:35:39 openvpn: Fri Oct  7 08:35:39 2022 Exiting due to fatal error
Oct  7 08:35:39 systemd: Started OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server.
Oct  7 08:35:39 systemd: openvpn@server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct  7 08:35:39 systemd: Unit openvpn@server.service entered failed state.
Oct  7 08:35:39 systemd: openvpn@server.service failed.
```

Comment: So what's in the log? It should log to syslog, so check `messages` or `syslog` or `daemon` file. Also you can try to start it by hand (not as a service) using `openvpn --config <config-file-name>` and see what it says.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Where can I read its log? Could you please share the path.

Comment: I found `openvpn-status.log` file in openvpn folder, but it is empty.

Comment: No, that's not a log file, but a status file that you defined. It is empty because it didn't started in the first place. Typically syslog writes its log files to `/var/log/`.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I shared the log after command `systemctl start openvpn@server.service`

Comment: `Oct  7 08:35:39 pandora openvpn: Fri Oct  7 08:35:39 2022 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)`

What is the system you are running it on? Is it OpenVZ or any other container (Docker, LXC)? If so, you're generally out of luck. This is not something which is typically done within a container.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Yes. A website is running on Docker Container. I have no way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the container it is only possible to create and use a `tun` device if the hosting provider gives your container such a possibility. They need:

- to load a `tuntap` driver on the host
- to give your container a permission to use it

**If this requirement is met**, you may create a missing device node and use it with OpenVPN or other applications:

```
mkdir -p /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
chmod 0666 /dev/net/tun
```

Probably you'll need to create it each time container boots, in which case it is convenient to create a systemd unitt which runs these commands for you and set it up to be required for network:

```
[Unit]
Description=/dev/net/tun device node
Requires=sysinit.target
After=sysinit.target
Documentation=https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=mkdir -p /dev/net
ExecStart=mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
ExecStart=chmod 0666 /dev/net/tun

[Install]
WantedBy=network-pre.target
```

Save this into `/etc/systemd/system/tuntap-dev.service` and run `systemctl enable tuntap-dev.service` to start it at boot.

Comment: But I am not going to setup a VPN Server as Docker container. Docker container is exist to run up my web site . I am going to setup a vpn server independent of Docker.

Comment: Then you must run the server not in the container. Your last comment hinted that you are running OpenVPN within a container, and this is what is need to run it in the container. There'll be no missing `/dev/net/tun` device node if you run it on the bare metal or in the VM, since it would appear normally (created by `udev`) in that case.

Comment: I got it. After run `mkdir -p /dev/net`
`mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200`
`chmod 0666 /dev/net/tun` and restarting OpenVPN its status change to `active`. Does it need to create `tuntap-dev.service`?

Comment: I'll suggest you to restart a container. If it happens everything was retained, you don't need a service. If the device node disappears, create a service and it will reappear each time, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1112488/why-cant-i-connect-to-the-openvpn-server-from-windows-client-to-centos-vps-even Can you give me a help?