# Why can't I connect to the OpenVPN server from Windows client to Centos VPS even though the VPN server is running?

Tags: openvpn, centos7, windows-10, vpn-client

I set up a `OpenVPN` Server on `Centos 7` and it is running perfectly. However, I could not connect to it from `Windows 10` client and receive errors below:

```
Fri Oct  7 21:10:32 2022 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Fri Oct  7 21:10:32 2022 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

As you can see my OpenVPN Server's status is `active` :

[image]

What I totally done, was copying these file from server to client machine:

```
ca.crt
client.crt
client.key
myvpn.tlsauth
```

To client server and creating `client.ovpn` file:

```
client
tls-client
ca D:\\OpenVPN\\ca.crt
cert D:\\OpenVPN\\client.crt
key D:\\OpenVPN\\client.key
tls-crypt D:\\OpenVPN\\myvpn.tlsauth
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication"
proto udp
remote 82.180.137.124 1194 udp
dev tun
topology subnet
pull
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-CBC
```

If somthing else need to be shared, let me know.

Comment: So well again, what's in the log file? I don't quite remember where it is in Windows, but it must be somewhere. Also, I suppose, the remote cert EKU must be TLS Web Server, because to the client the remote is a server. It is server who'd better say remote-cert-eku is web client. Sorry, I mean we need more logs, and consider what's going on the server too. Are you sure packets reach from the client to the server? Do you see the replies back? Increase verbosity (don't go over 5, it will not be useful for you).

Comment: I put all logs in the post

Comment: In fact, this all logs that OpenVPN throws.

Comment: How can I make sure of reaching packets from the client?

Comment: There's not a single error message in what you post.

Comment: I resolved them. Now I have ```Fri Oct  7 21:10:32 2022 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Fri Oct  7 21:10:32 2022 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed``` errors

Comment: Can you please put not the single line, but a whole lump of a log generated during a single connection attempt? Also, does *server* generate any logs when you try to connect?